# How C# resolve interface's "virtual" target?

Tags: c#, c++, interface, vtable

Let say I'm in `C++`, and I have this pseudo-interface (an `abstract class` with only `pure virtual methods`):

```
class IErrorLog
{
public:
    virtual bool closeLog() = 0;
};

class FileErrorLog : public IErrorLog
{
public:
    FileErrorLog(){}
    ~FileErrorLog(){}

    bool closeLog() { 
        std::cout << "Close FileErrorLog" << std::endl; 
        return true;
    }
};

int main()
{   
    FileErrorLog fileErrorLog;
    IErrorLog *log = &fileErrorLog;
    log->closeLog();
}
```

For what [I've learned](http://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/125-the-virtual-table/), `closeLog`, using the dynamic type of `IErrorLog`, is called devirtualizing that `vtable` of `FileErrorLog` and selecting the desidered target function (`closeLog()` pointer).

Since in `C#`'s `interfaces` are not really considered classes, when I do somethings like this:

```
interface IErrorLog {
    void closeLog ();
}

public class FileErrorLog : IErrorLog
{
    public FileErrorLog() {}

    public void closeLog() {
        Console.WriteLine("Close FileErrorLog");
    }        
}

public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        IErrorLog log = new FileErrorLog();
        log.closeLog();
    }
}
```

how C# will resolve that `closeLog()`? Is it the same mechanism?

Because here `IErrorLog log` isn't an `abstract class` anymore. Its a native type. Thus, I don't think `log` is a pointer to `FileErrorLog`.

Can you explain it to me?

Comment: Just because you refer to `log` through `IErrorLog` doesn't make it's actual type that. It's still in fact a `FileErrorLog`. IIRC C# uses the same design of a vtable in C++.

Comment: @SombreroChicken I think the c# design is a little different. Consider that in `FileErrorLog` you can implement both `closeLog` and `IErrorLog.CloseLog`(and if I'm not wrong, the latter would be called in OP scenario)

Comment: Here's a primer on old way it was done [.NET Framework Internals - Interface Vtable Map and Interface Map](https://web.archive.org/web/20150515023057/https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163791.aspx#S12). This model changed fairly substantially with [virtual stub dispatch](https://github.com/dotnet/coreclr/blob/master/Documentation/botr/virtual-stub-dispatch.md), but shows the "old-style" vtable interface dispatch.

Answer (score 5):

> how C# will resolve that closeLog()?

The runtime will resolve the call correctly by using an implementation-defined mechanism.

This mechanism is quite complicated in the case of interfaces, and there are interesting performance implications.

> Is it the same mechanism?

Is it the same mechanism as some C++ compiler uses for a different type system?  Almost certainly not.

The mechanisms however are *similar*, in that there are tables of function pointers hung off of the object instance pointer, and lookups are done at runtime to do the method dispatching.

> Thus, I don't think log is a pointer to FileErrorLog.

I assume you mean "managed pointer"; in C# we would prefer you to characterize references as "references"; unmanaged pointers are very different.

Since it is *false* that the managed pointers differ, you have a false belief. Anything that you've concluded from that false belief is the result of unsound reasoning and is not reliable.

Based on your question and a number of your comments, your core false belief seems to be that the in-memory representation of a reference to an object depends on the type of the variable that is being used to store the reference. **This belief is 100% completely false, so stop believing it right now**.  In the CLR, reference conversions are *representation preserving conversions*.

If a reference to an object of class type C is represented by the number 0x12345678, and you then convert that to a reference to interface I implemented by C, the representation is still 0x12345678.

> Any tutorial similar to that learncpp source for understanding C# behaviour?

This site is not for recommending tutorials.

Answer (score 1):

In C# (and all languages running on the CLI), references are to the object instance - not to a specific vtable or level in the inherited type hierarchy.  The compile-time typing is exclusively used to shorten the name of a method.  In the example type hierarchy of:

```
interface IFoo
{
    void Bar();
}

class CFoo : IFoo
{
    public virtual void Bar()
    {
    }

    void IFoo.Bar()
    {
    }
}

class CFoo2 : CFoo
{
    public override void Bar()
    {
    }
}
```

the "full" name used when emitting the `callvirt` opcode for `var foo = new Foo(); foo.Bar()` is `CFoo::Bar`.  The compiler just uses the type of the "RValue" to save you from typing it.

There are no casts or other conversions done at compile-time to call inherited methods.  The value of the reference remains the same regardless of the type specified in c#.

Consider the following calls in C#, and their equivalent IL encoding:

```
private static void CallFooBar()
{
    // L_0000: newobj instance void InterfaceDemo.CFoo::.ctor()
    CFoo foo = new CFoo();

    // Note that the next call (since the variable was typed CFoo) is not calling
    // the interface implementation.
    //                                              VVVV
    // L_0005: callvirt instance void InterfaceDemo.CFoo::Bar()
    foo.Bar();

    // L_000a: ret
}

private static void CallFooIFooBar()
{
    // Note that the type cast does not affect the value reference on the
    // stack (no cast is performed).  The instantiation looks identical to
    // CallFooBar above. 
    // 
    // L_0000: newobj instance void InterfaceDemo.CFoo::.ctor()
    CFoo foo = new CFoo();
    IFoo ifoo = foo;

    // Note that the call is made to the interface method (to be dispatched
    // through the interface method tables)
    //                                              VVVV
    // L_0005: callvirt instance void InterfaceDemo.IFoo::Bar()
    ifoo.Bar();

    // L_000a: ret
}

private static void CallFooIFooBar2()
{
    // Note that all of the compiled IL is identical to CallFooIFooBar
    //
    // L_0000: newobj instance void InterfaceDemo.CFoo::.ctor()
    IFoo foo = new CFoo();

    // L_0005: callvirt instance void InterfaceDemo.IFoo::Bar()
    foo.Bar();

    // L_000a: ret
}

private static void CallCFoo2Bar()
{
    // Note that all of the IL excepting for the newobj call is identical.
    // virtual method resolution takes place at runtime (or at JIT) - not 
    // at compile time.
    // 
    // L_0000: newobj instance void InterfaceDemo.CFoo2::.ctor()
    IFoo foo = new CFoo2();
    // L_0005: callvirt instance void InterfaceDemo.IFoo::Bar()
    foo.Bar();
    // L_000a: ret
}
```

The actual conversion from named method (ex: `IFoo::Bar` to the implementing method of `CFoo2::Bar`) is performed at runtime or at time of JIT - not at compile time.  In older runtimes, a `callvirt` instruction for an interface will be Jitted as:

```
; C#: ((IFoo)foo).Bar(); 
; C:  (*(foo->TypeHandle->InterfaceMap[0x30]))(foo)
mov ecx,edi                   ; move "foo" pointer into ecx 
mov eax,dword ptr [ecx]       ; Dereference to place MethodTable into eax
mov eax,dword ptr [eax+0Ch]   ; Dereference to interface map address
                              ; (offset 12 is constant for that version of
                              ; the CLR)
mov eax,dword ptr [eax+30h]   ; move the ifc impl start slot into eax 
                              ; (30h is discovered at time of JIT by
                              ; examining the loaded type hierarchy)
call dword ptr [eax]          ; call foo.Bar
```

The difference here from C++ is that the dereference to select the interface vtable is only done at JIT time and only for a call to an interface method.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is essentially the same as:

```
    FileErrorLog tmp = new FileErrorLog();
    IErrorLog log = tmp;
    log.closeLog();
```

You simply have an implicit *reference conversion* from a `FileErrorLog` to `IErrorLog`. The referenced object is in both cases exactly the same; reference conversions in c# are always identity preserving.

The call to the interface member `IErrorLog.closeLog` is then treated as a virtual call; IIRC interface members are virtual "final" members.

Comment: But you haven't a "class" reference. Interface isn't an class. Which kind of reference is used? Interface reference? Or even if interface is not a class (thus can't be an object) that syntax will be translated by compiler as "pointer to that object"?

Comment: @markzzz What does it matter? Both variables point to the same object, the only thing that changes is the type of the reference. A interface typed variable is a regular reference typed variable; its value is the "address" of the referenced object.

Comment: Yes, but IErrorLog "is-not-a" FileErrorLog. Its a "can-do" relation. Since its an interface, not a class. Its like a "struct" reference that point to a "class" object. You can't do that.

Comment: @Markzzz Huh? What has `struct` have to do with anything here? In c# an interface typed variable *is a normal reference typed variable*, it is most definitely nothing even remotely similar to a value type reference (struct). I'm not sure where you got that idea from but its absolutely wrong.

Comment: The confusion is that interface and class are different "thing" in c#. How can implicitly convert FileErrorLog into IErrorLog if they are basically two different "concept"? Its not a derived class that inherit from a base one (where cast make sense and do it automatically). Here interface is not an abstract class, is a different thing.

Comment: @markzzz The conversion is a *reference conversion*. The only thing that changes is the type of the variable. the object is untouched. And because the compiler *knows* that any `FileErrorLog` is an `IErrorLog`, the conversion is allowed. I'm not sure why you think a reference conversion between a class typed reference and an implemented interface typed reference should be disallowed.

Comment: To what point the reference log var? Its neither FileErrorLog nor IErrorLog object type (you can't instance an interface). I would say "to an object that represent a fixed part of FileErrorLog shared with interface, i.e. the methods of the interface. But again thats not a class :)

Comment: @markzzz `log` and `tmp` point to *same exact object*, I’ve told you that already several times. If you don’t believe it, simply do `ReferenceEquals(tmp, log)` and you will see that the answer is `true`.

Comment: @markzzz you seem to be very confused about the differences between the real type of an object and the type of the reference pointing to it; these  are two very different things; the only rule is that the real type and the reference type must be compatible; you cant have a dog variable pointing to a cat.

Comment: Exactly!!! Dog can't point to cat. At the same manner, a struct can't point to a class (my previous example). Here, why interface can point to a class? They are different things, as dog and cat. Since one don't inherit from another, why they are considered "compatible"? By design?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/166636/discussion-between-inbetween-and-markzzz).